# Change Option val into (SpecialType of val | DefaultType)

Tags: f#, fold

I got this bit of code to manage my connection state. I'm trying to learn F#. Now in the connect function I wan't to return my connected state, which needs a TcpClient. The try_connect_tcp function returns an Option TcpClient though. I tried the line `try_connect_tcp hostname port |> Option.fold Connected Disconnected` to return Disconnected if try_connect_tcp returns None. But it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```ml
type ConnectionState = 
    | Disconnected
    | Connected of TcpClient
    | LoggedIn of TcpClient * string

let try_connect_tcp hostname port =
    try
        Some(new TcpClient(hostname, port))
    with
        | :? ArgumentNullException -> printf "Empty Hostname"; None
        | :? ArgumentOutOfRangeException -> printf "Invalid portnumber"; None
        | :? SocketException -> printf "IDK MAN"; None

let connect connectionstate hostname port = 
    match connectionstate with
    | Disconnected -> try_connect_tcp hostname port |> Option.fold Connected Disconnected //HERE'S THE PROBLEM
    | _ -> connectionstate
```

Comment: Why does it not seem to work? What's the error?

Comment: `Option.fold` doesn't seem like a great use for this. Although it is possible, it's going to be awkward. Why not just use pattern matching? You seem to already know how that works.

Comment: ``Option`` has two states, while ``ConnectionState`` has three states. What are the rules for mapping from ``Option`` to ``ConnectionState`` other than ``None`` maps to ``Disconnected``?

Answer (score 2):

Why not change the `try_connect_tcp` function to work directly with the `ConnectionState` type?

```
let try_connect_tcp hostname port =
    try
        Connected (TcpClient (hostname, port))
    with
        | :? ArgumentNullException -> printf "Empty Hostname"; Disconnected
        | :? ArgumentOutOfRangeException -> printf "Invalid portnumber"; Disconnected
        | :? SocketException -> printf "IDK MAN"; Disconnected
```

**Edit:** If you really want to use `Option.fold`, the function passed to it requires two parameters. In your case, using your original `try_connect_tcp` function, you could write it like this:

```
let connect connectionstate hostname port = 
    match connectionstate with
    | Disconnected ->
        try_connect_tcp hostname port
        |> Option.fold (fun _ x -> Connected x) Disconnected
    | _ -> connectionstate
```